# Angular app URL conflicting with actual directory path inside app directory with Nginx 403 error

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I have an Angular App whose filesystem structure is as:

```
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── mycomp
│   │   ├── mycomp.component.js
│   │   ├── mycomp.module.js
│   │   └── mycomp.template.html
│   ├── app.config.js
│   ├── app.css
│   ├── app.module.js
│   ├── app.spec.js
│   ├── index.html
├── bower.json
├── e2e-tests
├── karma.conf.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
```

My `app.config.js`has a route as:

```
angular.
module('MyApp').
config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function config($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true
        });
        var myCompState = {
                name: 'myComp',
                url: '/mycomp',
                template: '<mycomp></mycomp>'
            };
        $stateProvider.state(myCompState);
    }
]);
```

So when I hit `http://app.localhost/mycomp` Nginx throws 403 Forbidden Error, as `mycomp`is a directory and I want to access it as Application Path.

`mycomp` directory inside `app` has only `.js`, `.css` and `.html` files.

My Nginx configuration is:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  app.localhost;
        root /usr/local/AngularApp/app;
        location ~ \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$ {
        }
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
```

How can I make Nginx rules such that if its a directory like path i.e., without any extension it uses only and only `/index.html` to resolve it?

Comment: Remove the `$uri/` clause from your `try_files` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks that works! But still there is one small problem, If I access `http://app.localhost/mycomp/` it redirects to `/home` as specified in `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');`

Comment: I don't see your index.html file.

Comment: @Satys see nginx configuration ( the last code snippet in question )

Comment: what i meant by i don't see your index.html is that I can't locate it in your filesystem architecture, anyways, after what @Richard suggested, do you mean 'http://app.localhost/mycomp' is working and this 'http://app.localhost/mycomp/' ain't, due to trailing slash?

Comment: Sorry my bad! I missed it! Now edited!
Yes, the later link is not working, it is trying to hit the server and find the directory path but not hitting `/index.html`